# Why does Eclipse load all plugins in a workspace?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 for developing Eclipse plug-in. In the same workspace, I have 2 Plug-in projects： projA and projB. No mater which project was run, both two projects will be loaded in the new Eclipse instance. If I only want to load projA, I have to close projB, why?
I run the project like this: right click the project and "Run as--- Eclipse Application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the [target platfom](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html)?

You can also edit your Run Configuration and choose the plugins to launch with.

Comment: Yes. RunConfigurations--Plug-ins---Launch with "plug-in selected below only". thx.

Answer (score 1):

The way you debug your project will start a new instance of Eclipse with all existing plugins installed(in your case,both project A and B are installed).This is typically called **self-hosting** in PDE.
If project A has no dependent package,just close other projects.